# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in VS2013

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to create New Project in my Solution in VS2013. The thing is I CANNOT. There's no error in my code prompting but whenever I try to Create new project, this error message appears.

> "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

I already tried to Clean the Solution, Rebuild, Build, but none of them seems to solve my problem. Can someone help me please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you try turning it off and on again? I mean restart computer. And start VS in safemode.

Comment: Oh. As simple as that. It worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the **Activity Log**. This may reveal the cause for that error.

You can find the *ActivityLog.xml* in the following place:

- Generally: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{VsVersion}\ActivityLog.xml`
- VS2013: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml`

For more Infos have a look at this helpful [blog-post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-extensions-with-the-activity-log/).